# Kivy - remove objects on touch_down

Tags: python, kivy

I have recently started playing with Kivy and would like to make a simple shooting game.

This is my code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
import random, time

a = Builder.load_string('''
<BattleField>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

<Target>
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'target.jpg'    

''')

class BattleField(Widget):

    #to destroy target
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        #if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        if self.collide_widget(self.target):
            self.remove_widget(self.target)

    def appear_target(self, *args):

        random_pos = tuple([random.randint(0, 600) for i in range(2)])
        self.target = Target()
        self.target.pos = (random_pos)
        self.add_widget(self.target)


class Target(Widget):

    pass

class ClockApp(App):

    def build(self):
        g = BattleField()
        Clock.schedule_interval(g.appear_target, 1)
        return g

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClockApp().run()
```

So for the moment it add a new target every 1 second. However, I have few problems here:

1. can remove only recently added widget
2. the recently added widget is removed regardless where I click.

Could someone please help me to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go (no many changes to your original post). You should have a look at [this page](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html) on the official documentation

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
import random, time

a = Builder.load_string('''
<BattleField>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

<Target>
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'target.jpg'    

''')

class BattleField(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BattleField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.appear_target, 1)


    def appear_target(self, *args):
        random_pos = tuple([random.randint(0, 600) for i in range(2)])
        target = Target()
        target.pos = random_pos
        self.add_widget(target)


class Target(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.parent.remove_widget(self)


class ClockApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return BattleField()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClockApp().run()
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I was playing with the code a little and found out that when not creating __init__ in BattleField and putting Clock in the App instead as before, it works too. Is there any special reason you did so? I will definitely read through the link you provided. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "self.parent.remove_widget(self.target)" instead of "self.remove_widget(self.target)"? To remove a widget, your code needs to act from a higher point in the widgets tree (I'd like to test yours but I don't have a computer right now).

Comment: I tried it but not even the most recent widget is not being removed afterwards. I feel like I am missing some important concept here in order to remove the older objects,